# Matlab 'idpoly' Simulation

Tags: matlab, validation, model, polynomial-math

I have managed to estimate an 'idpoly' m for my time series Z(1,:) using the 'arx' command in Matlab. Unfortunately I do not know how to use this model m for anything else.

How do I know input a second series Z(2,:) into the model to see how well it predicts on the validation data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lsim`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/lsim.html) to simulate your `idpoly` with an arbitrary time input.

Arnaud